# What is the difference between "losfahren" and "losgehen"?

Tags: verb, verb-choice, verb-usage

The bus driver drove off after picking up passengers at the stop.

> Der Busfahrer fuhr los, nachdem er Fahrgäste an der Bushaltesstelle aufgenommen hatte.

Can I also use *losgehen* in this context? What is the difference between *losgehen* and *losfahren*?

Comment: No, you cannot. *Losgehen* means "start walking, leave by foot". The difference between *losgehen* and *losfahren* is, quite logically, that between *gehen* and *fahren*.

Comment: What did your own research show? Which of the explanations you looked up do you need help with?

Comment: @RegDwight LEGO-Projekt?! Bist du Däne? Coole Tierchen :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Im Englischen benutzt man "to go" um irgendwohin zu gelangen ("I go to Europe", "I go to the store", "I go by train"). Das sagt nicht unbedingt etwas darüber aus, wie man dahin kommt. Im Deutschen bezieht sich gehen immer auf die eigenen Füße (to walk). Deshalb kannst Du "losgehen" hier nicht verwenden, denn das würde heißen, dass der Busfahrer den Bus verlässt und irgendwohin geht (läuft).

Comment: Die Fahrt *geht los*, sobald alle Fahrgäste eingestiegen sind. – "Losgehen" also contains the meaning of "to begin". However, it must be associated with some kind of action, activity, or event; and a bus driver is certainly not the correct sort of noun to represent such a thing.

Comment: See the italics "in this context" in the original question...

Answer (score 6):

In standard German "gehen" almost always means "to go by foot". To make matters worse, however, there are a few exceptions:

It can mean to emigrate, or move somewhere for some time:

> Ich gehe für ein Jahr nach Spanien.

It can mean "to work", as in "operate properly":

> Geht dein Computer jetzt wieder?

It can mean "to be available, to have time":

> Wann geht es denn bei Ihnen?

There are other fixed expressions as well:

> Wie geht es dir? (How are you feeling?)
>   Es geht schon (Mustn't grumble.)
>   Das geht dich nichts an! (That's none of your business!)

To answer your original question, though: No, you cannot use losgehen here as you're clearly not referring to movement by foot.

Since that would be too easy, though, there are a few other cases where `losgehen` refers to something else, like the start of an event (Wann geht das Match los? Geht's bald los?) or an explosion (Plötzlich ging die Bombe los).

Comment: See the italics "in this context" in the original question... jeez, guys, you don't have to add all possible uses of a word in an answer...

Comment: Following that logic, "no" would have sufficed. Not the most thoughtful answer, though.

Comment: That would be the other extreme and equally not helpful. That's why I kept my answer to what was actually asked, not extending it to Gott und die Welt. In the days of tl;dr that makes most sense to me.

Comment: Well, I didn't see any harm in providing a few more examples. Feel free to read as much or little as you want.